# How can I make this variables change depending on a value?

Tags: python-3.x

how can I make the following variables acquire the name of the main variable next to them? (a,b,c,d) change depending on MainVariable?

```
MainVariable = 'Shoe'

a = blackShoe
b = whiteShoe
c = blueShoe
d = yellowShoe
```

and if it changes to for example 'Tie'
then

```
a = blackTie
b = whiteTie
c = blueTie
d = yellowTie
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `if` statements?

Comment: Is value of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` string?

Comment: Read up of if statements and string concatenation

Comment: yes values a,b,c,d are strings

Answer (score 1):

```
 a,b,c,d = [s + MainVariable for s in [a,b,c,d]]
```